# Using vba for vlookup from a different file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to use `vlookup` where the reference is another file. The reference table is from cell `a2` to `a300`. The lookup value is from cell `G2` to end of column. The `vlookup` is to be done in column `AA`.

I found the code below on one of the solutions on this website, but have no idea how to change it to suit my file.

```
Sub SBEPlannerAdder()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OUROBOROS\Desktop\30-5-19\vba\VBA\Gents_SW_May'19.xlsb")
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OUROBOROS\Desktop\30-5-19\vba\VBA\1st phase stores.xlsx")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C300")


    For rw = 2 To twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
       twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 2, False)
    Next rw

extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZffs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cItpL.png)

Comment: As your reference table is only a single column, are you just checking the values in G exist in the table?

Comment: yes, so i know which cells to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You'll need to adjust the workbook and sheet names to suit.

Not sure what output you are expecting, I have just added a text message in the output cells in AA.

```
Sub y()

Dim rw As Long, x As Range, v As Variant
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook 'file with lookup values (containing code)
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OUROBOROS\Desktop\30-5-19\vba\VBA\1st phase stores.xlsx") 'file with reference table
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A300")

For rw = 2 To twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    v = Application.Match(twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 0)
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, "AA").Value = "Found" 'G is in the table
    Else
        twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, "AA").Value = "Not found" ''G is NOT in the table
    End If
Next rw

extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: If the file containing the lookup values is the one with the code you can just use `Set twb =thisworkbook`.

Comment: It works great,is there any way to get rid of the file path for the current workbook?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didnt notice the comment

Comment: Theres a problem with the code, its displaying not found in all cells

Comment: Need more info. If you are running code repeatedly, you should clear the output cells first.

Comment: i have i clear them everytime, could there be a problem with the match function

Comment: The values in G must not be found in the table. Without knowing anything about your data, hard to provide more detail, but check for leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Is there anyway i can attach the excel sheets here

Comment: Not files, but you can add screenshots to your question.

Comment: attached 2 screenshots, Thanks for all the help

Comment: Afraid I can't really tell anything from them - try stepping through your code using F8 to see what's going on, and add a breakpoint on the not found section. Somewhere along the line it is not finding the values in the table - check your references as well.