# Vlookup using path in cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to create a tool that makes changes to a file that is selected as File1 in a workbook:

[image: tool]

When I click "run past dues" the macro runs that makes changes in File1. In this macro, I want to use a vlookup that looks up files in File2 of which the path is in the tool workbook.

Everything works fine up untill this Vlookup. I cannot seem to get the macro use the path of File2 to lookup a value and paste in in File1.

Can someone help me with this? See the VBA code below:

```
Sub Past_dues_button12345()
'Macro to create past due list daily
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim File As String
Dim File2 As String

File = Sheets("Tool").Range("B2")
File2 = Sheets("Tool").Range("B3")

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(File)

remove_repair
add_columns_with_comments
add_data_new_column
vlookup
pastevalues
Sharewb

End Sub


Sub add_columns_with_comments()

    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column3]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PN"
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column2]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MRPc"
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comment"
    
End Sub

Sub vlookup()

    Range("H2").Select
'%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Do not know how to get the macro to lookup values of File2 here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([File2]Sheet1!R2:R1000,8,0)
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H538")
    Range("H2:H538").Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using vba for vlookup from a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561117/using-vba-for-vlookup-from-a-different-file)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use clear references for both workbooks, and avoid using select statement, it will make your sub a lot easier to understand and faster.

Then try `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Something like that:

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As worsheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As worsheet
Dim my_range As Range

'create reference to the original workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet_to_paste")

'create reference to the opem workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(File)
set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'set your vlookup range
Set my_range = ws2.Range("R2:R1000")

'vlookup your value
my_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(value_to_lookup, myRange, 8, 0)
'paste your value
ws1.Range("H2") = my_value

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens here is that "File2" (or "File" in your code) is not recognized since this file is not found in the active workbook. (the file path is in the tool, not in File1)